# How to get model instance inside a DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider derived class?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-2-metadata

How can I get a model instance inside a DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider derived class in MVC2? To be more precise, how can I get the model instance to which a property belongs, inside a GetMetadataForProperty derived method?

Comment: I want to create a custom ModelMetadataProvider, inheriting from DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider. Then I want to override the method GetMetadataForProperty, and inside the new custom definition of the method, get the model instance to which the property being evaluated belongs to.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Part of DataAnnotations are used for validation. There are two separate DataAnnotations providers, one for Validation, and one for Metadata. I want to create a custom provider for metadata.

Comment: No, it has nothing to do with validation. I want to set some specific metadata properties acording to the values of some of the model properties, i.e.: ShowForEdit, ShowForDisplay, TemplateHint,...